proposition 16.8 in "introduction to smooth manifolds" by John M. Lee
I have a question about a detail in proposition 16.8 of John M. Lee's introduction to smooth manifolds. Here's the statement of the proof :

Proposition 16.8 (Integration Over Parametrizations). Let M be an oriented
smooth n-manifold with or without boundary, and let $\omega$ be a compactly supported
n-form on M. Suppose $D_1,\dots,D_k$ are open domains of integration in $\mathbb R^n$, and for
$i=1,\dots,k$, we are given smooth maps $F_i:\bar{D_i} \rightarrow M$ satisfying
(i) $F_i$ restricts to an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism from $D_i$ onto an open subset $W_i\subseteq M$;
(ii) $W_i \cap W_j=\varnothing$ when $i\neq j$ ;
(iii) $\text{supp}\;\omega \subseteq \bar W_1 \cup \dots \cup \bar W_k $.
then
$$\int_M\omega=\sum_{i=1}^k\int_{D_i}{F_i}^*\omega\quad\text{(16.3)}$$
$\mathit Proof$. As in the preceding proof, it suffices to assume that $\omega$ is supported in the domain
of a single oriented smooth chart $(U,\phi)$. In fact, by restricting to sufficiently
nice charts, we may assume that U is precompact, $Y=\phi(U)$ is a domain of integration
in ${\mathbb R}^n$ or ${\mathbb H}^n$, and $\phi$ extends to a diffeomorphism from $\bar U$ to $\bar Y$ .
For each i, define open subsets $A_i \subseteq D_i, B_i\subseteq W_i$ and $C_i\subseteq Y$ (see Fig. 16.8) by
$A_i=F_i^{-1}(U\cap W_i)$,$\;$ $B_i=U\cap W_i=F_i(A_i)$ $\;$ $C_i=\phi(B_i)=\phi\circ F_i(A_i).$
Because $\bar D_i$ is compact, it is straightforward to check that $\partial W_i\subseteq F_i(\partial D_i)$,and therefore $\partial W_i$ has measure zero in M, and$\mathbf{\; \partial C_i=\phi (\partial B_i)\; \text{has measure zero in}\; \mathbb R^n.}$
...

this may seem like an obvious question, but why $\partial C_i=\phi(\partial B_i)$ has measure zero in $R^n$?
I think since $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism and Y is a domain of integration, $\partial U$ should have measure zero in M, and since $\partial B_i$ is a union of a subset of $\partial W_i$ and a subset of $\partial U$ , it should have measure zero in M, so its image under the diffeomorphism $\phi$ has measure zero in $R^n$. Is this reasoning correct?

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

thanks for the tip. I quoted the statement of the proof instead.

We are still lacking specifics. Is $\partial D$ smooth? At any rate, the relevant fact is that $C^1$ equidimensional maps send sets of measure zero to sets of measure zero.

I believe so. The boundary of an $n$ dimensional smooth manifold with boundary is itself an $(n-1)$ dimensional smooth manifold without boundary. Thanks for the answer
